# raw_input hang on python2.7.3 on raspberry pi

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, freeze, raw-input

I am building a small robot based on a raspberry pi and a pic microcontroller (pic16f1937). Basically raspi is taking a picture, looks for a specific object (a green ball for example), generate commands (rotation to the left or to the right for some degrees, go farward, go backward, take the object, free the object) and send them on a serial (ttl rs232) link to microcontroller.

Raspi program is made using Geany 1.22 , Python 2.7.3 and opencv.

Pic program is on hitech c, but is irelevant at this moment.

My problem (at this moment) is that I want to use more than one objects and I want to be asked by raspi if I want it to continue bringing me more objects after every object it brings. For that i am using :

```
continue=''
continue=raw_input('do you want to continue? y=yes   n=no')
if(continue):{do some stuff}
```

But the programs pauses/hangs on the line containing `raw_input` instruction. No error is displayed and I have to stop it.

Do you have any idea about what could be the problem? If yes, please help me.

Comment: I think it's very hard for us to figure out what might be going wring... I'm not a RaspPi expert here... how are you getting input to the raspPi (ie to answer the question)?

Comment: You might have better luck on Electronics SE: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/raspberry-pi

Answer (score 0):

Actually, `continue` is a reserved word in python.
So there is no way this could ever work, you would get a SyntaxError.

Also, raw_input returns a string of whatever was typed in, so unless enter was pressed immediately, the string will be non-empty, and will evaluate as True (even if 'n' was typed).